preserving comments with vite?
I'm trying to get vite to user terser and preserve some comments. Well, any comments at this point. This is the build section of my vite config:
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    vueDevTools(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    },
  },
build: {
    minify: 'terser',
    terserOptions: {
      compress: {
        drop_console: [
          ,'log'
          ,'table'
          ,'warn'
        ],
      },
      format: {
        comments: true
      }
    }
  }

I can run my build and see that it preserves console.error and drops console.log calls, but no matter what I do, it strips all comments. Even ones that should be there by default. I've tried comments: 'all' as well and no luck. It still strips out things like  /** @preserve Foo Bar */ which is the example from the docs at https://terser.org/docs/options/. I've also tried using options instead of format with the same lack of results.
Why do I want the comments? At this point it is to simply make sure I can. If the docs say I should be able to control what comments are in the output, then we need to make sure that's the case. If not, put in a bug report to either fix the code or the docs.
But I suspect it is something I'm not doing right.
Thanks
